# Hide a particular record in django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

I am accessing all records from a model in a table with `for` loop. I've added one button to each row. When I click that button that particular row is removed, but when I refresh the page all removed rows appear again. But I don't want to show them again. How can I do this?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
         <th>Firstname</th>
         <th>Lastname</th>
         <th>Check Out</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
          {%for s in student %}
          <tr class="hiderow">
             <td>{{ s.first_name }}</td>
             <td>{{ s.last_name }}</td>
             <td id="hidebtn"><div class="btn" role="group" aria-label="...">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="$(this).closest('tr').remove()">Check out Now</button>
             </div></td>
          {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make AJAX request to the server and actually remove this entry from database to be permanent.

Comment: I don't want to remove that record permanently from database. I want to keep there as it is, just try to avoid from query access

Comment: Then add a flag in database (lets say add field ```is_active```) and set it to ```False``` with ajax. Then you can create query like ```<model_name>.objects.filter(is_active=True)```

Answer (score 0):

For finding the solution that fits your case, it's important you understand why the removal doesn't survive a page reload with your approach. Your `onclick` JavaScript snipped modifies the DOM. The server has no idea this is happening and the browser will throw the current DOM away on refresh and will build a new DOM from the HTML it newly gets from the server.

Should a button remain hidden for **all browser sessions of a user**, or even for **all users**? Then you'll need some server-side state for it. (See [Domen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29759211/674064) for that.) Probably another model that holds foreign keys to the models the buttons are based upon.

Should a button only remain hidden for **current session**, i.e. for the browser tab on which it was removed? Then you can get by without hitting the server, e.g. by holding the state in a modified URL. (Encode the state in a `#....` suffix, and get it back from there upon a page refresh.) Of course, you're still free to hold the state on the server side for this situation, too. You'll probably want to associate it with some kind of session representation. (Not sure what Django has in that regard.)